# DNS server Error in IE6 While running asp.net solution

Tags: c#

when i run my asp solution in Virtual PC in XP mode that was builded in windon 7,I found an IE6 Problem that means DNS server error and cannot open the page .

I'm Using IIS Express and It can access from VPC.
I can run the internet and my solution from VPC but sometime the DNS server error is occured.

The problem is Although the Solution can run in correctly but sometime I click a link , the IE6 give me the message {the Page cannot open}

In Window7 i'm using IE9 and in VPC XP mode i test by the IE6.
Although the Same Solution this error does not occur In IE9.

I hope Someone can give a hand to me .
thanks a lot.

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/03/05/microsoft_sends_flowers_to_ie6_funeral/